# How to save the content of a text file into a linked list?

Tags: java, linked-list

I am trying to write a program that saves the content of a text file into a singly linked list, every line in the txt file is a node. I used Scanner to read from the file but I am having trouble placing the Text into a linked list.
            I created a linked list class and a Node class. 
            Any hint or help is would be helpful.
            This is my Linked list class:

```
        import java.util.Iterator;

        public class LinkedList<T> { //Generic
            private Node<T> myStart;
            private Node<T> myEnd;
            private int mySize;

            public LinkedList(){
                mySize = 0;
                myStart = null;
                myEnd = null;
            }


            // Clears the List
            public void clear(){
                myStart = null;
                myEnd = null;
                mySize = 0;
            }

            public T getFirst(){
                if (myStart == null){
                    return null;
                }
                return myStart.getValue();
            }


            public boolean isEmpty() {
                // Returns ONLY and ONLY IF "myElements" equals to 0
                return mySize == 0;
            }

            public int size() {
                return mySize;
            }

            //Add a value to the list
            public void add(T aValue ){
                Node<T> theNode = new Node<T>(aValue);
                theNode.setLink(myStart);
                myStart = theNode;
                myEnd = theNode;
                mySize++;
            }

      //Adds a value to the end of the List
            public void addToEnd(T aValue){
                Node<T> theNode = new Node<T>(aValue);
                if(myEnd == null){
                    myStart = theNode;
                    myEnd = theNode;
                }
                else {
                    myEnd.setLink(theNode);
                    myEnd = theNode;
                }
                mySize++;
            }

            //Removes a value from the list
            public void remove(T aValue){
                Node<T> current = myStart;
                Node<T> previous = null;
                while(current !=null){
                    if(current.getValue().equals(aValue)){
                        mySize--;
                        if (previous == null){
                            myStart = current.getLink();
                        }
                        else{
                        previous.setLink( current.getLink() );
                        }
                    }
                    if(current == myEnd){
                        myEnd = previous;
                    }
                    previous = current;
                    current= current.getLink();
                }
                return;
            }

            //Prints the current list
            public void print(){
                Node<T> current = myStart;
                while(current !=null){
                    System.out.print(current.toString() + " ");
                    current= current.getLink();
                }
                    System.out.println();
            }

        }
```

Then I tried to read in the file which I could but I don't know why its not printing the List correctly. Here is where I added the file into the linked list:

```
 public class SpellCheck<T> {

        public SpellCheck(){

        }

        //LoadData reads the file and places it in a linkedList
        public static String loadData(String fileName){
            LinkedList<String> dictionary = new LinkedList<String>(); //Create a new LinkedList called dictionary
                Scanner scan = null;
                try {
                    scan = new Scanner(new FileInputStream(fileName)); //read in the file
                } 
                catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                while(scan.hasNext()) {
                    String theList = scan.nextLine();
                    dictionary.add(theList); //Add theList to the LinkedList "Dictionary"
                    System.out.println( dictionary ); //print it out
                }
                scan.close();
                }
    }
```

My text file has random words such as:
aback
abaft
abandon
abandoned
abandoning
abandonment
basketballs
baskets
basking
Basque
bass

In my Test Driver this is what I did in my TestDriver class:
    public class TestDriver {

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LinkedList<String> theList = new LinkedList<String>();
        theList.add(SpellCheck.loadDataLinkedList("standard.txt"));
        theList.print();
        }
}
```

Comment: This: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29140402/how-do-i-print-my-java-object-without-getting-sometype2f92e0f4

Answer (score 0):

```
LinkedList<String> dictionary = new LinkedList<String>(); 
System.out.println( dictionary ); //print it out
```

You need to write a function for `LinkedList` that will print the contents of the `LinkedList` in the way you want.

Right now it will only print the memory address of `dictionary`.

You will need to loop through the list and pick up the `String` stored in every `Node` and print it.

Something like this:

```
public void printList() {
    Node<T> node = getFirst();
    do {
        // get the String print it and move to the next node
    } while (node.myEnd != null);
}
```

EDIT: or use what @9000 wrote for printing.

Comment: I have tried my print statement with other objects and it prints fine though

Comment: What does it print. Does it print something readable or a bunch of characters.

Comment: Well I tried my print method with another testDriver and I did theList.add(20); theList.add(14); and it printed the integers. But with this, it prints: LinkedList@42a57993 for every word in the text file. I am not sure if it has to do with the object type

Comment: Printing an object itself will always return the address, not a property of an object. `LinkedList@42a57993` tells you its a Linked List with the address `42a57993` as far as Java is concerned it is doing its job. `System.out.println(box)` will be memory address akin to what you are getting now, `System.out.println(box.color)` will be whatever is stored in the `color` property of `box`.

Comment: Search SO for more info, this is a common question. One example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29140402/how-do-i-print-my-java-object-without-getting-sometype2f92e0f4

Comment: Thank You! Checking it out now. I just thought that maybe it had to do with my testDriver because I felt like I was adding it twice. Once in the loadData method and again in the TestDriver by calling 'theList.add(...);'

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you take a top-down approach, and also use standard classes. (Reinventing a wheel may be fun, but sometimes you're better off with battle-proven wheels from `java.util`.)

Consider:

```
public LinkesList<String> readLines(BufferedReader source) {
   LinkedList<String> result = new LinkedList<>();
   while (true) {
      String line = source.readLine();
      if (line == null) break;  // end of file
      result.add(line);
   }  
   return result;
}

LinkedList<String> loadFile(Sting filename) {
   BufferedReader reader = null; 
   try {
     reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));
     return readLines(reader);
   } finally {
     // free up the file, exception or not.
     // yes, this happens before the return, too.
     if (reader != null) reader.close(); 
   }
}
```

Printing a list (and, in fact, any iterable) is also dead easy:

```
List<String> lines = ...;
for (String item : lines) {
  System.out.println(item);
}
```